# Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.fnCustomDate", or the name is ambiguous

Tags: sql-server, function

I working on a basic function and tried executing but it doesn't work and throws the below error
"Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.fnCustomDate", or the name is ambiguous."

Below is the Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCustomDate]
(
    @DateFormat AS DATETIME
)
RETURNS VARCHAR (MAX)
AS
    BEGIN
        RETURN  DATENAME(DW,@DateFormat) + ' ' +
                DATENAME(D,@DateFormat) +
        CASE
            WHEN DAY(@DateFormat) IN (1, 21, 31) THEN 'st'
            WHEN DAY(@DateFormat) IN (2, 22) THEN 'nd'
            WHEN DAY(@DateFormat) IN (3, 23) THEN 'rd'
            ELSE 'th'
        END + ' ' +
                DATENAME(M,@DateFormat) + ' ' +
                DATENAME(YY,@DateFormat)    
    END
GO
```

Trying to execute it on a table for date column:

```
Select [dbo].[fnCustomDate](column name)
from [dbo].[tablename]
```

Comment: My guess is that all you need to do is connect to a database from your Management Studio.  `dbo` doesn't mean anything absent the context of a given database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.fnCustomDate", or the name is ambiguous."

This error is returned when the function is not found.  Simple things to check:

Are you connected to the correct database?

Is the function spelled correctly?

Does the schema dbo exist?

Is my function in the dbo schema?

NB: There is nothing incorrect with the function, or how you are calling it in the example that you have provided.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!. I was missing the database name in front of he function when i was calling it. Select [databasename].[dbo].[fnCustomDate](column name)
from [dbo].[tablename]. This worked. Thanks for your input.